# Handling an EditText that was added programatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I've been making all of my views dynamically, and now I've come to the point where I want to add an EditText for people to write in.

I've been able to accomplish this for the most part, but it doesn't look right. I have a linear layout that I'm adding a relative layout to. I'm making the relative layout have a white background, then adding the EditText. Problem is, it always adds it to the direct center of the relative layout, and options to align it vertically to the top have so far failed.

I also need to be able to pull the text from it later when a separate button was pressed (I know how to make the button work, it's the pulling text from it part I'm a bit iffy on). Here's my code so far:

```
public void addEditText(LinearLayout L){
    EditText myEditText = new EditText(c);
    myEditText.setSingleLine(false);
    RelativeLayout l1 = new RelativeLayout(c);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(scWidth1, 300);
    lp.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;

    l1.setLayoutParams(lp);
    l1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    l1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    l1.addView(myEditText);
    L.addView(l1);
}
```

Comment: That did it! You should post that as a response so you can get credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);` places the `EditText` in center vertical of the parent container i.e `RelativeLayout`, remove that line.